# How to select Boolean operators based on value in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame.

```
col1      |    col2       |      col3      |     col4

  5            Upper              3               2

  80           Lower              1               10
```

I want to do some Boolean operation on this data frame, add a new column and store the result in it.

When the col2 value is 'Upper',

```
col1 <= col3 * col4
```

when col2 value is 'lower',

```
col1 >= col3 * col4
```

I will either get True or False from these operations which I want to store it in 'col5' column.

I used df.iat to go through every single row and get data and done the operation manually. Performance is very bad for my dataset. Is there other possible way with way better performance to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
prods = df['col3']*df['col4']
df['col5'] = np.where(df['col2']=='Upper', 
                      df['col1'] <= prods,
                      df['col1'] >= prods)
```

Comment: This is perfect for either this or that operation. Thank you. np.where goes for if true then second argument else third argument. What if I want to use, let's say, 5 different boolean operations based on the column value. In my example, I only used Upper and Lower. What if there's like a, b, c, d as values and I want to use < for a, > for b, == for c, != for e

Comment: @JeevaBharathi `np.select`.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into documentation for np.select for more info. Thank you kindly.